# Eureka Image Row Won't Save to Object

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am using the Eureka iOS framework to create a form. One of the rows is an image row that allows users to attach an image. I have the below object:

```
struct Report {
    var title: String?
    var detail: String?
    var immactions: String?
    var recommactions: String?
    var notifications: String?
    var identified: String?
    var date: String?
    var time: String?
    var origDept: String?
    var origOwned: String?
    var images: [UIImage]?
}
```

I then set my object:

```
var newReport = Report()
```

And then I take the dictionary of values from my form and try to save the image to the images array from the object:

```
if key.hasPrefix("Image") {
      newReport.images?.append((value)! as! UIImage)
}
```

When I print out the newReport object, the images array is nil. If I change the above to this:

```
if key.hasPrefix("Image") {
         print (value as! UIImage)
    }
```

then it prints the following:

```
<UIImage: 0x1c42ab220> size {1536, 1152} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
```

So I know there is an image in there but for some reason it is not getting saved to the images array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to append UIImages to an optional array that hasn't been initialized. Before you use it, initialize it like so:

```
newReport.images = [UIImage]()
```